# Counting vowels in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I need to count vowels in text in C++.  I have this sample code in PHP that accomplishes this. Is there a straightforward way to implement this in C++?

```
<?php 
$text = 'Sample Text';
echo strlen(preg_replace('/[^aeiouy]/i','',$text)); 
?>
```

Note that I'm a beginner.

Comment: "my friend needs this tonight"... uhm, your friend, sure... Could have better disguised your homework.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the obvious code:

```
std::string const vs("aeiouAEIOU");
int count = std::count_if(text.begin(), text.end(),
    [&](char c){ return vs.end() != std::find(vs.begin(), vs.end(), c); });
```

Comment: Nice use of modern language features. It will only pick up lower-case vowels though, whereas the original PHP snippet was case-insensitive.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield: fair enough - I'm quite oblivious of PHP (although I should have picked up the regular expression...). I used a low-tech fix.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach would be to write a `for` loop which goes through each character in your string. On each iteration, check if the current character is a vowel (upper or lower case presumably). If so, increment a counter.